# Has Bruce Banner ever received legal punishment for his behavior as the Hulk?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I read [The Incredible Hulk #153: The World, My Jury!](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_153) recently.

In that comic, the Hulk/Banner is put on trial for his many crimes. It's a kangaroo court, with Matt Murdock (Daredevil) serving as his defense lawyer.

At the end of the trial,

> Mr Fantastic shows up and uses a device he just invented to empower the Hulk, allowing him to escape by jumping through the ceiling, before he can be sentenced to death.

Has the Hulk or Banner, in any continuity, ever actually been sentenced by a court for the destruction he's caused? Has he ever served the penalty, whether it be jail-time, execution, a fine, or whatever?

Comment: By legal punishment do you mean being imprisoned by government forces sanctioned by legitimate governing bodies or going through due process and the various legal procedings? Because he has gone through the former but not the latter as far as I know. The former being just as much a legal punishment as the latter as it would fall on government forces to carry out these sanctions. Also, in many cases Banner would be considered not responsible due to not being able to control Hulk reasonably and at worse would be sentenced to anger management ^.^

Comment: @Durakken I mean going through a judicial process. I would consider incarceration by the Hulkbusters as being akin to an arrest prior to a trial, for example.

Comment: Then I think never, but as I said, he'd realistically get sentenced to Anger Management. It would be an interesting story idea, but the outcome, if they follow what they law would be, it would be an obvious outcome.

Comment: If ever there was a case that would stand up to the standard for "temporary insanity," it would have to be Bruce Banner/The Hulk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bruce Banner has stood trial for the death of 800 civilians in Ultimates Volume 2 #3 (which takes place in the Earth-1610/Ultimates universe).

Banner loses the trial, but is tricked before the verdict is announced, so that he may be drugged and transported to a death sentence.

[UncannyXMen.net provides a synopsis](http://uncannyxmen.net/comics/issue/ultimates-2-3):

> Bruce Banner stands on trial for the murders he committed as the Hulk. With only blind lawyer Matt Murdock standing at his defense, it looks like the trial is a foregone case, with the public at large demanding an immediate execution of the doctor. Even all of the Ultimates believe Banner should pay for what he did, despite their friendship with Betty. Betty herself later has a final, emotional conversation with Bruce and can’t even get close to him, because the guards refuse to open the doors to his cell for her. As the trial progresses and things become even grimmer for poor Bruce, Nick Fury lies to him that he has won his freedom back. Believing Fury, Bruce drinks a bottle of champagne without realizing it has been tranquilized. He collapses, and Fury and the Ultimates leave Banner behind on a departed ship flight deck. As they all leave, Bruce suddenly opens his eyes again, right before the deck detonates! Captain America and the others grant Bruce a funeral and later go to a bar together. When Hank gets home again, he receives a mysterious phone call from someone who just wanted to thank him. Elsewhere, on an unknown location, Bruce Banner merges into a large crowd and disappears in it.

Comment: +1, looked that summary over. Want to note that the prosecution framed the super-soldier serum as a drug, and compared Banner's culpability to someone who killed people on crack cocaine. They also compared his lack of memory while hulked out to someone who killed people while blacked out on alcohol.